# How to link css file to fxml file

Tags: css, fxml

I want to link CSS file to FXML file via the FXML file, but coud not find an answer that solved me that problem (tried some solutions but it did not work for me).
The CSS and FXML files are in the same package.
The CSS file is empty for now but I tried to style button for example and it did not worked for me.
This is the FXML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<Pane prefHeight="503.0" prefWidth="649.0"
    style="-fx-background-color: #7d7d7d;" styleClass="test"
    stylesheets="@styles.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171"
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="">
    <children>
        <Label layoutX="118.0" layoutY="103.0"
            text="Private account code/employer code:">
            <font>
                <Font name="System Bold" size="24.0" />
            </font>
        </Label>
        <TextField layoutX="251.0" layoutY="141.0"
            promptText="Enter your code here" />
        <Button id="btnExit" fx:id="btnExit" layoutX="-1.0"
            layoutY="-1.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#getExitBtn"
            prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="36.0"
            style="-fx-background-color: #F25022;" text="X" textFill="WHITE">
            <font>
                <Font name="System Bold" size="18.0" />
            </font>
        </Button>
        <Label layoutX="156.0" layoutY="11.0" prefHeight="53.0"
            prefWidth="331.0" text="W4C Identification" textFill="#383838">
            <font>
                <Font name="System Bold" size="36.0" />
            </font>
        </Label>
        <Label layoutX="128.0" layoutY="245.0" prefHeight="35.0"
            prefWidth="410.0" text="Or identify by external QR reader:">
            <font>
                <Font name="System Bold" size="24.0" />
            </font>
        </Label>
        <Button layoutX="235.0" layoutY="172.0" mnemonicParsing="false"
            onAction="#Send" prefHeight="51.0" prefWidth="180.0"
            style="-fx-background-color: #7FBA00;" text="Next" textFill="#383838">
            <font>
                <Font name="System Bold" size="24.0" />
            </font>
        </Button>
        <Button layoutX="235.0" layoutY="280.0" mnemonicParsing="false"
            onAction="#Send" prefHeight="51.0" prefWidth="180.0"
            style="-fx-background-color: #7FBA00;" text="Click here"
            textFill="#383838">
            <font>
                <Font name="System Bold" size="24.0" />
            </font>
        </Button>
        <ImageView fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0"
            layoutX="225.0" layoutY="339.0" pickOnBounds="true"
            preserveRatio="true">
            <image>
                <Image url="@../../images/W4C.png" />
            </image>
        </ImageView>
    </children>
    <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@styles.css" />
    </stylesheets>
</Pane>
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not get it to work in that manner either. So instead of:

```xml
<stylesheets>
    <URL value="@styles.css">
</stylesheets>
```

I embedded it within my root element (in my case a `BorderPane`), like so:

```xml
...
<BorderPane stylesheets="@styles.css">
    <!--
        Anything within this BorderPane will have styles.css applied to it
    -->
</BorderPane>
...
```

And that worked perfectly for me.